# не могу сбросить отступы margin padding на bootstrap 3, и почему то к заголовку не применяется цвет

Tags: css3, html5, bootstrap

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head 
content must come *after* these tags -->
<title>Bot</title>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.0/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.min.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="">
<script src="fontawesome/fontawesome-all.js"></script>
<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media 
queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<h2>nlnlknklnkln</h2>
</div>
</div>


<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/common.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: а important! применяли?

Comment: да получилось. Но почему когда я пишу h2 {color: red}; Оно не применяет а background применяет...